# LUB and GLB of a function

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Find the least upper bound (LUB) and greatest lower bound (GLB) of $\{x\sin(1/x):x>0\}$

My Attempt:
Since limit of given function is $0$ as $\lim_{x\to f(x)}g(x) = 0$ when $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded. So $\operatorname{LUB}(f) = \operatorname{GLB}(f) = 0$ But it don't resemble with actual answer. Please help me.

Comment: "LUB" is the least upper bound of the function over the set of interest, i.e. the $\sup$. You are confusing it with the limsup as $x\to 0$. Similar for "GLB".

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I got LUB = $2/π$ and GLB = $-2/3π$. Am I right ? If yes then I'm wrong with actual answer. One of the answer is GLB < $-2/3π$

Comment: @Gae. S , Please see my comment. I'm right or wrong.

Comment: Also consider the behavior of the function as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I do not see where you got the LUB and GLB values. The local extrema of this function do not occur at nice neat fractions of $\pi$ or their inverses. One trick that might be helpful is to substitute $t = \frac 1x$ as the variable. The resultant function of $t$ will have the same extrema, though at different locations.

Comment: Please use correct [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty. For example, use `\{...\}` for the set you are defining, and `$\lim_{x\to ???}f(x)g(x)$` renders as $\lim_{x\to ???}f(x)g(x)$ (I would have edited it in, but I am struggling to work out some of your meanings).